# Adiciona Player Html5 automaticamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou procurando uma maneira de adiciona o player Html5 nas paginas do meu site.

Eu possuo  videos em mp4, que estão embedados.

Gostaria de tranforma esses videos em Html5 aplicando um novo player na pagina.

Exemplo:

```
  <embed src="http://meusite.mp4?id=1as5df7asd" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid">
```

Estou procurando uma maneira que toda vez que tiver http://meusite.mp4?id=1as5df7asd

seja adicionado um novo player em Html5 na pagina:

```
<video controls="controls" height="430" poster="" src="http://meusite.mp4?id=1as5df7asd" width="680"></video>
```

O objetivo é jogar o link em Mp4 que tiver na pagina dentro do html5

isso me pouparia muito tempo, pq teria que procura em todos os artigos, e edita-los manualmente.

Algum Script verifica se na pagina existe alguma embed ou link cujo endereço seja http://meuite.mp4?id= e a ID 1as5df7asd

e encontrando joga o link ou a id dentro do codigo Html5.

O objeito é transforma meus videos em mp4 em Html5. como todos os videos estão hospedados em um servidor apenas a Id do video é diferente.

As Embed estão nesse formato:

Bastaria jogar a id   para dentro do link em mp4

Fazendo um novo player na pagina.

```
  <video controls="controls" height="430" poster="" src="" width="680"></video>
```

Comment: Amigo o que a TAG `actionscript-3` e `java` tem haver com a sua questão?

Comment: Nossa você mudou totalmente o contexto da questão. Tudo bem vamos começar do zero, da onde vem esses IDs?

Comment: Porque não fazes essa substituição no servidor? no JavaScript vais ter de fazer cada vez que a página carregar... no servidor farias só uma vez.

Comment: @Sergio ele quer embutir vídeos de outros servidores como o uol, youtube, vimeo, etc dentro da tag vídeo, mas como eu disse na resposta  "Você não pode acessar diretamente o video e embarca-lo usando a tag <video> pois o próprio google bloqueia ou usa urls dinâmicas", ou seja ele quer algo aparentemente impossível.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** que está é uma "pergunta camaleão" (do meu ponto de vista) e a resposta é sobre está questão https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/45339/2

A sua questão inicial:

> *Q:* Eu possuo videos do Youtube, Vimeo e videos em mp4.
>
> Eu possuo esse codigo:
>
> Exemplo 1
>
> ```
> <video width="640" height="360" id="player1" preload="none">
>      <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI" />
> </video>
> ```

### Os problemas

- O mimetype `video/youtube` não existe
- Páginas `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...` são do tipo `text/html`, portanto não é o endereço do video mas sim o endereço da página HTML.
- Você não pode acessar diretamente o video e "embarcá-lo" usando a tag `<video>` pois o próprio google *"bloqueia"* ou usa *"urls dinâmicas"* como:

  ```
  https://r1---sn-upfn-bg0l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?&dur=337.106&expire=1419848481&...&range=0-1031
  ```

  Portanto este caminho é totalmente incorreto

### Como compartilhar

O próprio YouTube e Vimeo fornecem maneiras de compartilhamento dos seus vídeos

- [Vimeo](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/229326167-Share-features):

  Clique no desenho do avião e copie o código gerado, exemplo:

  [image: vimeo share]
  <sub>(fonte: [vimeocdn.com](https://secure-a.vimeocdn.com/images_v6/help/faq/ins_share_button.jpg))</sub>
- [Youtube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780):

  Com YouTube você pode embarcar um player em flash:

  ```
  <object height="350" width="425">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/OdT9z-JjtJk" />
  <embed height="350"
         src="http://www.youtube.com/v/OdT9z-JjtJk"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425"></embed>
  </object>
  ```

  Ou usar `<iframe>` (recomendável):

  ```
  <iframe allowfullscreen="" width="420" height="315"
          src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UkWd0azv3fQ#t=2m30s"></iframe>
  ```